# Sorting Algorithm running in an Embedded PC

Tags: sorting

I need to use a sorting algorithm in a list that has as much as 500,000 elements. This program runs on an embedded PC. Does anyone knows which sorting algorithm has the best performance in time complexity as well as in memory?

Comment: Does running on an embedded PC change the problem in any way?

Comment: What are the specs of the embedded PC?

Comment: I think that it might, not because of the embedded computer itself but because of the processor's speed and the computer memory. The processor is running at 200Mhz and it has 128Mb of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values of the items are not very large (8-bit or even 16), you should try one Integer Sort, like Counting sort or other
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Answer (score 1):

Some good information about sorting algorithms can be found at http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: But I think it's important to know how much extra memory does each algorithm needs.

Comment: I can't really answer that, but look at the implementations of the algorithms and try to deduce from that how much additional memory you must allocate except for the original set of data. I have no idea what the original data is, but say for example that you have 500,000 elements of 4-byte ints, then the entire list is only occupying ~2MB of RAM. The overhead of a memory expensive sorting algorithm shouldn't be too much of a problem with 128MB of RAM (depending on what else is running at the same time on the machine of course).